# selecting max values grouped by two column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple table like this

```
firstname, lastname , nb_payments
a, b , 10
a, b , 20
b, a , 30
b, a , 40
b, b , 50
```

I want to select the 3 max payments grouped by the couple firstname, lastname

The output desired is like this

```
firstname, lastname , top3
b, a , 70
b, b , 50
a, b , 30
```

I did this query :  `SELECT firstname, lastname , nb_payments as top3 FROM account ORDER BY nb_payments DESC LIMIT 3`

But it doesn't add up nb_payments grouped by the couple firstname,lastname

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the payments and group by `firstname` and `lastname`

```
SELECT   firstname, lastname , SUM(nb_payments) 
FROM     account 
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
ORDER BY 3 DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This query is not going to work, since it first sums up all payments by per account and orders/limits afterwards. The way I understand it is that OP wants the sum of the top three payments per account for all accounts.

Comment: @TimoSta If this is indeed the OP's requirement, you are correct, and this query is faulty.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you very much , it was exactly what i needed . top three payments grouped by last name and first name

Answer (score 1):

I think this produces the output you want:

```
select firstname, lastname, sum(nb_payments)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname
                                order by nb_payments desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by firstname, lastname;
```

Comment: Works too thank you very much but i prefer the easier solution of Mureinik because i am still beginner in sql

Comment: @user902509 . . . The two queries do very different things.  Mureinik's returns three rows *after* all rows have been aggregated.  This aggregates only three original rows, but returns all combinations of names.  The latter is my interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i can write in oracle, if it helps. there are other ways also.

```
select * from(
    SELECT firstname, lastname , sum(nb_payments) as top3 FROM test group by firstname,lastname ORDER BY top3 desc )
    where rownum <=3
```